# Can't install postprocessing with pip

Tags: python, post-processing

I'm new to python,

in a tutorial video they have the line `import postprocessing as pr`,

however I receive error `Error: No module named 'postprocessing'`

But `pip install postprocessing` doesn't work, I get error `No matching distrubution found for postprocessing`

**Edit:** apparently this may be a postprocessing.py file somewhere that wasn't released.

**How do I use / install postprocessing in python?**

Comment: which operating system you are using?

Comment: Could you be more specific as to which package you're trying to install? "Postprocessing" is a little generic (and there is indeed no matching package on pip). If you're not entirely sure which package it is, a link to the tutorial video would help.

Comment: at 2:35 in a video by Siraj: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ogrJaOIuBx4 and I'm using mac

Comment: someone linked to https://pypi.org/project/mpop/ in the comments, but I don't see how this would be the postprocessor

Answer (score 2):

To see if it is installable with pip u can search  [pypi library](https://pypi.org/) to find out.

You've mentioned it's a video tutorial, are you sure you didn't miss out on a step you need? probably to create the postprocessing.py file so that you can import from there?

I reckon the best way to know should be to ask in the comment section of the tutorial site.

Comment: the video isn't very descriptive, it appears to assume a higher level of python understanding than I currently have